# add a subdirectory to a site hosting wordpress in doc root

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to run a php script on my site from a newly created subdirectory.

However I am finding that my existing wordpress blog (running from doc root) is intercepting my url to the script in subdir and giving me a 404.

How can I get wordpress to ignore the subdirectory?

EDIT: based on comment, here is my .htaccess file contents:

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName example.com
AuthUserFile /home/xxx/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/xxx/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You'd probably have to add a condition to your `.htaccess` file. If you can, quote it here so somebody can show you where to add the condition.

Comment: Pekka, if you put your comment as an answer, i will credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on pekka's comment, I fixed my own problem with following (where folder1 is the subdirectories i want wordpress to ignore):

```
=========[ start of .htaccess snippet]==========
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#
# stuff to let through (ignore)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder1/"

# other existing rules go here:
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
#
====================[ end ]=====================
```

Pekka, if you put your comment as an answer, i will credit you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(stats|failed_auth\.html).*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule . - [L]
</IfModule>
```

This one worked perfectly for me.

Source: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Making_stats_accessible_with_htaccess